# Python: invalid syntax for a while loop

Tags: python

I am a beginner python user working on python 2.5.4 on a mac.
I have been trying to create the game stock ticker (text only) in python for the last few days and I am almost finished, but I am getting "Syntax error: invalid syntax" on a while loop. Here is   the part of the code thats giving me problems the error occurs at line 5 and I get a ^ pointed at the e of while.  (I would post the whole thing but its over 300 lines)

```
while (keep_going ==0):
            sell_var = int(raw_input('Please choose what you would like to sell, for grain enter 1, for technology enter 2, for ore enter 3, for construction enter 4, for bonds enter 5, and for trade enter 6, to skip enter any other key'))
            if sell_var == 1:
                temp_sell = int(raw_input('How many grain stock would you like to sell?')
                while (temp_sell > playgrain[x]):
                    temp_sell = int(raw_input('Please choose a different amount to sell, you do not have that many stock')
                playgrain[x] = playgrain[x]-temp_sell
                playmoney[x] = playmoney[x] + stock[1] * temp_sell
            if sell_var == 1:
                temp_sell = int(raw_input('How many technology stock would you like to sell?')
                while (temp_sell > playertech[x]):
                    temp_sell = int(raw_input('Please choose a different amount to sell, you do not have that many stock')
                playtech[x] = playtech[x]-temp_sell
                playmoney[x] = playmoney[x] + stock[2] * temp_sell
            if sell_var == 1:
                temp_sell = int(raw_input('How many ore stock would you like to sell?)
                while (temp_sell > playore[x]):
                    temp_sell = int(raw_input('Please choose a different amount to sell, you do not have that many stock')
                playore[x] = playore[x]-temp_sell
                playmoney[x] = playmoney[x] + stock[3] * temp_sell
            if sell_var == 1:
                temp_sell = int(raw_input('How many construction would you like to sell?)
                while (temp_sell > playconst[x]):
                    temp_sell = int(raw_input('Please choose a different amount to sell, you do not have that many stock')
                playconst[x] = playconst[x]-temp_sell
                playmoney[x] = playmoney[x] + stock[4] * temp_sell
            if sell_var == 1:
                temp_sell = int(raw_input('How many bonds stocks would you like to sell?)
                while (temp_sell > playbonds[x]):
                    temp_sell = int(raw_input('Please choose a different amount to sell, you do not have that many stock')
                playbonds[x] = playbonds[x]-temp_sell
                playmoney[x] = playmoney[x] + stock[5] * temp_sell
            if sell_var == 1:
                temp_sell = int(raw_input('How many trade stock would you like to sell?)
                while (temp_sell > playtrade[x]):
                    temp_sell = int(raw_input('Please choose a different amount to sell, you do not have that many stock')
                playtrade[x] = playtrade[x]-temp_sell
                playmoney[x] = playmoney[x] + stock[6] * temp_sell
```

Comment: The mismatched syntax highlighting should give you some other areas to adjust. You have mismatching `'` for most of your input prompts.

Comment: Indent your code using 4 spaces.

Comment: Some unasked-for advice: there's a programming principle called "Don't repeat yourself", DRY, and the basic idea is that if you're writing a lot of code which looks just like other code except for a few minor changes, you need to see what's common about the pattern and separate it out.  In this case, I would use dictionaries to store the cost and amount of different stocks.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the closing `")"`

```
int(raw_input('How many grain stock would you like to sell?')
                                                             ^
```

in a number of places, you may want to go back and look over your code.

This should be:

```
int(raw_input('How many grain stock would you like to sell?'))
                                                             ^
```

and as you can see from the code coloring, some of your strings don't terminate. E.g.,

```
temp_sell = int(raw_input('How many ore stock would you like to sell?)
                                                                     ^^
```

needs a terminating single quote, *and* closing `")"`:

```
temp_sell = int(raw_input('How many ore stock would you like to sell?'))
                                                                     ^^
```

One way to minimize/avoid these sort of problems is to use an **editor that does matching** for you, ie it will match parens and sometimes quotes. And clearly **syntax highlighting/coloring** is a very useful tool as it shows when quotes aren't closed (and in some language multi-line comments aren't terminated). It would be worth examining the code in those areas too.

*As an aside*, there are a lot of `if sell_var == 1:` one after the other .. is that intentional? In which case it seems one of them should suffice.

Finally, you may want to take   a look at **[PEP8 - The Style Guide for Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)**, it'll give suggestions on formatting, naming conventions etc when writing Python code. For instance the body of your loop is indented too much (though that may just be an artifact of pasting your code here). E.g., [PEP8 recommends 4 spaces for indentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Comment: Thank you so much, i completly missed that.

Comment: @user1644240 It happens .. it's worth looking into an editor that will highlight matching parens and quotes.

Comment: In keeping with the `(` theme, `while (keep_going == 0):` can be re-written as `while not keep_going:`

Answer (score 0):

```
        if sell_var == 1:
            temp_sell = int(raw_input('How many ore stock would you like to sell?)
```

Your forgot a `'` and a `)` there.